# ng-select stop displaying invalid value

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have a ng-select component with list of options sent to as items. But ngModal value is not in the items i.e. invalid. But ng-select component still displays the invalid value. The behavior is not same for native select components with options. There, invalid value does not show up. Is there any way (other than programmatically iterate through the items and comparing model value) to detect and not display invalid value in ng-select?

Comment: You should select proper value if it's invalid. Otherwise Angular will create additional option with ngModel value

Comment: How does this work with native select component then?

Comment: You mean `<select>`?

Comment: Yes, with *ngFor options

Comment: `ngFor` just list elements, and does not actually validate if it's valid or not

Comment: Correct, and it stops displaying invalid model value. But same is not happening for ng-select.